# Передача данных в метод другого класса для рисования

Tags: java, swing

Главный класс

```
package test1;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;


public class Test11 extends javax.swing.JFrame implements MouseListener {

public Test11() {
    super();
    addMouseListener(this);
}
Test22 test22 = new Test22();    

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Mouse Cliked!");
    test22.x1=e.getX();
    test22.y1=e.getY();
    test22.paint();   
}
}
```

Второй класс

```
package test1;

import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Test22 {
public int x1,y1,x2,y2;

public Graphics g;   

public void paint(){
   System.out.println("Paint");       
   x2=100;
   y2=100;
   g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
   System.out.println("!Line!"); 
}     
}
```

Требуется чтобы рисовал линию с координатами мыши при клике.
Но у меня проблема с инициализацией. Я не понимаю как я должен сделать, чтобы все заработало.

Вот что говорит мне консоль(метод срабатывает, но рисовать не хочет):

```
-Mouse Cliked!
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"java.lang.NullPointerException
-Paint
at test1.Test22.paint(Test22.java:18)
at test1.Test11.mouseClicked(Test11.java:25)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в `Test22` объявлено поле `Graphics g`, но ему ничего не присваивается, поэтому оно всегда `null`, что и приводит к исключению. Проще всего переработать метод `Test22.paint`, чтобы он принимал все нужные параметры:

```
public static class Test22 {
    public int x2, y2;

    public void paint( Graphics g, Point point ) {
        System.out.println("Paint");
        x2 = 100;
        y2 = 100;
        g.setColor( Color.BLACK );
        g.drawLine( point.x, point.y, x2, y2);
        System.out.println("!Line!");
    }
}
```

Дальше нужно при вызове где-то достать требуемые значения. `Graphics` можно взять у фрейма, точку с координатами клика - у события мыши:

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Mouse Cliked!");
    test22.paint( this.getGraphics(), e.getPoint() );   
}
```

Рисование прямо на фрейме плохо тем, что при перерисовке фрейма (например при сворачивании или изменении размеров окна), все нарисованное стирается. Поэтому лучше завести невидимую картинку в памяти, рисовать линии и прочее на ней, и выводить всю картинку при перерисовке разом. Можно создать отдельный компонент, который будет этим всем заниматься:

```
public class PaintPanel extends JPanel {
    int width, height;

    // "холст" в памяти, на котором все будет рисоваться.
    BufferedImage canvas;

    Test22 test22;

    // Будем считать, что test22 - это инструмент рисования
    public PaintPanel( int width, int height, Test22 test22 ) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        // можно использовать обычный BufferedImage
        //canvas = new BufferedImage( width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB );
        // но использование "совместимого" BufferedImage позволяет
        //  Java2D оптимизировать копирование при отрисовке
        canvas = createCanvas(width, height);

        this.test22 = test22;

        // для обработки нажатия мыши воспользуемся анонимным классом
        //   от MouseAdapter, чтобы не переопределять все методы интерфейса MouseListener
        addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased( MouseEvent event ) {
                // создаем новый графический контекст для "холста",
                //   чтобы наши настройки цвета, штриха и т.п. не помешали
                //   другим операциям рисования
                Graphics2D g2d = canvas.createGraphics();
                test22.paint( g2d, event.getPoint() );
                // освобождаем контекст
                g2d.dispose();

                // сообщаем, что наш компонент неплохо было бы перерисовать
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    // создание совместимого "холста", заливка фона белым
    private BufferedImage createCanvas(int width, int height) {
        BufferedImage result = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()
                .getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration()
                .createCompatibleImage( width, height );

        Graphics2D g2d = result.createGraphics();
        g2d.setColor( Color.WHITE );
        g2d.fillRect( 0, 0, width, height );
        g2d.dispose();

        return result;
    }

    // переопределенный метод отрисовки компонента выводит "холст"
    @Override
    public void paintComponent( Graphics g ) {
        g.drawImage( canvas, 0, 0, null );
    }

    // предпочтительные размеры панели - по размеру холста
    //   для некоторых LayoutManager'ов стоит аналогично переопределить
    //   getMinimumSize и getMaximumSize
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension( width, height );
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
public class Test extends JFrame {

    static void initUI() {
        Test frame = new Test();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );

        Test22 test22 = new Test22();

        frame.setContentPane( new PaintPanel( 800, 600, test22 ) );

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( Test::initUI );
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Разобрался.